# Starteam to X migration? (where X is one of: svn/git/hg/bzr ...)

Tags: svn, git, version-control, migration, starteam

Is there a tool that can migrate Starteam to svn or git or any other modern/decent source control system?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of how `git-svn` works; allowing you to use git to pull from an svn repository.

Something that can import a StarTeam repository and convert it to an svn repository, but also keep pulling from Starteam and adding to svn.

Hell, even a "starteam to cvs" tool would be fine, as long as I can keep pulling from the starteam repo after the initial migration.

Comment: How I would like to not use StarTeam at work...

Comment: @dalle (I know this is late) but StarTeam is a luxury compared to VSS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used polarion's SVN Importer for StarTeam to Subversion migration.  I believe it has an incremental import available that would allow you to continue to update your subversion repository over time. but I've only done full one shot exports from StarTeam into Subversion.

http://www.polarion.com/downloads/svn.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently investigating options to do this. It seems very feasible, and once you get into some sort of version control software (vcs), it is not too difficult to migrate to another.

Here are some results I have found (note that there are multiple forks of some of these):

- https://github.com/planestraveler/git-starteam
- https://github.com/warrenfalk/git-st
- https://github.com/flyskywhy/git-starteam

Note that StarTeam has change request and change tracking that you would not get unless you were using some server client like GitLabs or Github, where you can track issues and bugs.