# how to check out all versions of starTeam version control tool

Tags: version-control, starteam

how to check out all versions of starTeam version tool.
I wanted to check out all versions for particular file and that way i wanted to do it for all of my files on production server.
can anyone suggest what are the available options.

Comment: If you haven't Borland StarTeam, try to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357707/starteam-to-x-migration-where-x-is-one-of-svn-git-hg-bzr

Comment: i have Borland StarTeam, but i am asking how can i checkout all verions of file from starTeam.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, is your intention to check out all the *labelled* versions of a project from starteam in some automated manner?

If so, then I think you will want to use the "**stcmd**" command-line tool that comes with starteam.

---

### 'stcmd' location

- For Linux: It resides in the "starteam/bin/" sub-folder of your install
- For Windows: It resides somewhere like "C:\Program Files\Borland\StarTeam SDK 14.0\lib\stcmd.exe"

---

### Performing checkout via 'stcmd'

The stcmd checkout command is "**stcmd co ...**" (followed by various parameters). Here's a dummy example:

> stcmd co -p
>   "**USER**:**PASSWD**@**SERVER**:**PORT**/**PROJ**/**VIEW**"
>   -cfgl **LABELNAME** -eol lf -o -rp **/local/path/to/working/folder** -filter MOI

Replace the items in bold with your username, password, server address+port, project-name, view-name, label-name and checkout-path (working folder).

You can learn more about the various other stcmd checkout parameters (eg, -eol, -o, -filter) by typing:

```
stcmd co -?
```

It's worth assessing those extra parameters to decide if they are what you need in your scenario, or if you prefer different settings to this.

---

### Getting a list of all labels in a view

Ok, so you can now checkout, but the other aspect of your question I think is the ability to iterate through a set of checkouts (where I think you intended to check out each individual label).

So to get a list of labels, you can do it this way:

> stcmd list-labels -p
>   "**USER**:**PASSWD**@**SERVER**:**PORT**/**PROJ**/**VIEW**"

...or alternatively, the stcmd tool now has an sql-like querying system that might do the trick too, but I couldn't get it to work this way:

```
stcmd connect username@server:port
stcmd set project = PROJ view = VIEW
stcmd select Name from Label
```

This presently results in an error, even though I think it ought to work that way, so it might be a bug worth reporting to microfocus on their forums at this location (if you're interested in that approach):

http://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/starteam/f/

---

### Putting it all together

After you've got your list of labels and the ability to check out the label, hopefully you'll be able to fuse the two mechanisms together in some sort of scripting language that suits you.

---

### Via the StarTeam SDK

Another approach to this could be to write a java app that makes use of the starteam SDK (this is Microfocus' java-api for starteam).

This path will take a bit more elbow-grease and time, the SDK has the reward of giving you more control and access to the database information than the stcmd tool can provide.

---

### Conclusion

So my guess is that for your initial needs, some scripted use of stcmd will get the job done for you. If you need more details than the stcmd tool can give you, you might have to dig into the StarTeam SDK as an alternative.